# Appending error message in jQuery and showing in span + AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using AngularJs. I am creating a error message in the controller.js file and want to send the error message to index.html . I have used the below code, but not sure how to pass it to the span element and also remove the character "," from the error message. Below is the code used:

//controller.js

```
$scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = false;

 $scope.add = function () {

        if (!$scope.mainForm.$valid) {
            alert("Form is not valid")
        }
        else {
            var msg = "Please select ";

            if ((jQuery('#startDatepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                msg = msg + "Start Date";
            }
            if( (jQuery('#endDatepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                msg = msg + ",End Date";
            }

            if ((jQuery('#startTimepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                msg = msg + ",Start Time";
            }
            if ((jQuery('#endTimepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                msg = msg + ",End Time";
            }
};
```

I wan to pass the "msg" to index.html, which I currently have as:

```
<span class="error" ng-show="submitted == true && isAllDateTimeMissing"></span>
```

Also, another issue is if only end date is having value as empty, then I want to remove the character "," from the message. 
How to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**remove the character "," from the error message**

> Use a flag like as isMessaged for checking if any comma have added functionality

// Js code

```
$scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = false;    
 $scope.add = function () {            
        if (!$scope.mainForm.$valid) {
            alert("Form is not valid")
        }
        else {
            var msg = "Please select ";
            var isMessaged = false;

            if ((jQuery('#startDatepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                msg = msg + "Start Date";
                isMessaged = true;
            }
            if( (jQuery('#endDatepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;

                msg = isMessaged == false? msg+ " End Date":  msg + ",End Date";
                isMessaged=true;
            }

            if ((jQuery('#startTimepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                msg = isMessaged == false? msg+ " Start Time":   msg + ",Start Time";
                isMessaged=true;

            }
            if ((jQuery('#endTimepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                msg = isMessaged == false? msg+ " End Time":  msg + ",End Time";
            }

$scope.FinalMessage=msg;
};
```

**but not sure how to pass it to the span element**

//html code

```
<span class="error" ng-show="submitted == true && isAllDateTimeMissing">
    {{FinalMessage}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Store `msg` in your **scope**:

```
$scope.msg = "Please select ";
```

**2)** When you update it, don't forget to update it **in scope**:

```
if(...) {
    $scope.msg += ", End Time";
} else if {
    ...
}
```

**3)** And finally, in your span:

```
<span class="error" ng-show="submitted == true && isAllDateTimeMissing">
    {{msg}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a message on the view, then put the string on $scope in the controller & use ng-bind or {{msg}} to display it.

Eg.
Inside Controller:
`$scope.msg = "Please select ";`

On the template:
`<span class="error" ng-show="<your condition>" ng-bind="msg"></span>`
OR
`<span class="error" ng-show="<your condition>">{{msg}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

For removing ',' simple code.

```
 $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = false;
 $scope.add = function () {

        if (!$scope.mainForm.$valid) {
            alert("Form is not valid")
        }
        else {
            var msg = "Please select ";
            var errMsg = "";

            if ((jQuery('#startDatepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                errMsg = errMsg + "Start Date";
            }
            if( (jQuery('#endDatepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                errMsg = errMsg + ",End Date";
            }

            if ((jQuery('#startTimepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                errMsg = errMsg + ",Start Time";
            }
            if ((jQuery('#endTimepicker').val() == ""))
            {
                $scope.isAllDateTimeMissing = true;
                errMsg = errMsg + ",End Time";
            }
            if(errMsg.charAt(0)==","){
                        errMsg.substr(1);
            }

            msg = msg + errMsg;
};
```